# How to creating point features and add data in attibute table at the same time?

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcmap, arcobjects

I created point features. but ı cant do add data attribute table.

```
IMxDocument pMxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IPoint pPoint = pMxdoc.ActivatedView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
IFeatureLayer pFLayer = pMxdoc.FocusMap.Layer[3] as IFeatureLayer;
IWorkspaceEdit pWSE = ((IDataset)(pFLayer.FeatureClass)).Workspace as IWorkspaceEdit;
pWSE.StartEditing(false);
pWSE.StartEditOperation();

IFeature pFeature = pFLayer.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
pFeature.Shape = pPoint;
pFeature.Store();

// I want to add data in table this here but how?

pWSE.StopEditOperation();
pWSE.StopEditing(true);

pMxdoc.ActivatedView.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3):

You´re only assigning a geometry to the feature, but you may need further attributes. Thus you should set the attribute-values for your current feature using [`set_Value`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Value_Property/0025000007vv000000/):

```
int fieldIndex = myFeatureClass.FindField(attributeName);
object newValue = "newValue";
IFeature pFeature = pFLayer.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
pFeature.set_Value(fieldIndex, newValue);
pFeature.Shape = pPoint;
pFeature.Store();
```